# Autodek forge viewer background color

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Actually I change the background color in the forge web viewer using the setBackgroudColor command then the TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT is fired,
but, this cause a flashing effect

so, is it possible to initialize the color while initializing the GuiViewer3D, using the config paramters ?

Luc

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's feasible. Here are two approaches.

1. Change it after loading the model.

```js
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => {
  viewer.setEnvMapBackground(false); //!<<< Turn off background image
  viewer.setBackgroundColor(255, 226, 110, 219, 219, 219); //!<<< Change background color
}, { once: true }); // once run this handler once

viewer.loadDocumentNode(document, bubble);
```

2. Use [profile API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/profiles/) to change that

```js
const aecProfileSettings = Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.AEC;
const customAecProfileSettings = Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.clone(aecProfileSettings);
customAecProfileSettings.settings.envMapBackground = false;

const customAecLightPreset = {};
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.copyLightPreset(
  Autodesk.Viewing.Private.LightPresets.find(preset => preset.name == customAecProfileSettings.settings.lightPreset),
  customAecLightPreset
);
customAecLightPreset.bgColorGradient = [255, 226, 110, 219, 219, 219];
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.LightPresets.push(customAecLightPreset);
customAecProfileSettings.settings.backgroundColorPreset = JSON.stringify(customAecLightPreset.bgColorGradient);
customAecProfileSettings.settings.lightPreset = customAecLightPreset.name;
const customAecProfile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(customAecProfileSettings);

viewer.start();
viewer.setProfile(customAecProfile);

const documentId = `urn:${urn}`;
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
```